# how to get the value of the hidden list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've a hidden field in my jsp

```
< s: hidden id ="lstId" value = "obj.lstVendors" / >
```

Is it possible to get the list in javascript using

```
document.getElementbyId(lstId)?
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the `id` in quotes :

```
var elem = document.getElementbyId("lstId");
```

and to get the value

```
var val = document.getElementbyId("lstId").value;
```

The [MDN is a good place for JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

Comment: how do i take these values in java script?
Will var lstArray = document.getElementbyId("lstId"); work?

Comment: @user1372469 to get the value you use `.value;` - updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If it is rendered as an HTML element with the same ID, then yes.